# How to align the title in the middle?

Tags: javascript

I'm working with codepen.io and I am creating a paragraph.
The graph has a title.

The problem is that I want the title center-aligned.It should automatically set the title in the middle, not about editing the value of "x". I can't use CSS to do this, and I believe javascript would do the job.

Here are the one functions I am using to draw the title and the link to my project goes bellow.

```
var text = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"text");
    text.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 100);
    text.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', 15);
    text.textContent = (titel); 
document.getElementById("bargraph").appendChild(text);
```

Full code:

[codepen.io/Cleanwater/pen/LWQyJm?editors=0010](http://codepen.io/Cleanwater/pen/LWQyJm?editors=0010)

Comment: "Schieberöffnung" ..  should be vertically and horizontally aligned ?

Comment: It's a word in another language. It should be horinzontally aligned.

Comment: Isn't it ?
it looks like it is

Comment: what browser are you using ?

Comment: Now it is in the middle, but if I change the title than it's not in the middle anymore. It should automatically be placed in the center, like when you use in CSS text-align: center;

Comment: I'm using firefox

Comment: please explain the difference between middle and horizontal align

Comment: If you do not understand what I want, just ask direct. I just want the title be in the center/middle

Comment: so you do indeed mean vertically and horizontally aligned ?

Comment: if it helps me than yes

Comment: it was really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var text = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"text");
    text.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', 15);
    text.textContent = (titel); 
document.getElementById("bargraph").appendChild(text);
    text.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 300 / 2 - text.getBBox().width /2);
```